# Why there is space and p in last line in output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

```
a = "ns "
for i in  a:
    print(i,end = "p\n")
```

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i71o2.png)
Why there is space and p in last line in output ????

Comment: because the string variable `a` is a 3 character string, with the last character being a space

Comment: Because the last element of your a variable is a space. Just remove it and set a = "ns"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your string contains a space and \n is treated as a line break, leaving a p at the end of each line.